# Polymer - Paper Badge inside a Paper Tab

Tags: polymer

When doing

```
<paper-tabs ...>
    <paper-tab ...>
       <paper badge label="4" ..>
..
```

The badge only shows inside the tab, the other half that is outside the tab element is hidden like behind something.

How can i get the full icon to show?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your limited example, I wasn't able to reproduce the exact symptoms you describe. However, I encountered a similar problem where the badge was repositioned out of view when the `iron-select` event fired. As a workaround, I added [`for="_"`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-badge#property-for) to `<paper-badge>`:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-badge/paper-badge.html">
</head>
<body>
  <style is="custom-style">
    paper-badge {
      --paper-badge-margin-left: 60px;
      --paper-badge-margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  </style>
  <paper-tabs selected="0">
    <paper-tab>
      <span>TAB 1</span>
      <paper-badge for="_" label="4"></paper-badge>
    </paper-tab>
    <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
  </paper-tabs>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/LZpJBb?editors=1000)</sup>